# How to define the place (node) of an additional replica (pod) on OpenShift?

Tags: replication, scaling, openshift-origin

I have a master-node configuration of OpenShift. I have created an application. I have a pod of the app running on node1. Now I want to create an additional pod (on node2). I know you can create additional pods with the following command:

```
oc scale rc rcname --replicas=2
```

But now your kubernetes master will decide on which node your new pod will take place (the best place, so maybe also on node1). But I want to make this decision by myself (place it on node2). 
I know you can use a `--selector` for defining your node when you're creating a container.

But I don't know if you can use this for replicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to choose exactly where the scheduler will place the next pod that your replication controller creates.

You can configure various weights and scheduling affinities by managing the `schedulerConfigFile` contents.  Take a look at https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/scheduler.html for the different options.  You set the location of your scheduler config in the master-config.yaml (https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/master_node_configuration.html).

Comment: Okay, didn't know that, Thanks